# Speeding up Wordpress on a Local Network

Tags: plugins, php, css, javascript, google

Currently I'm trying to run WordPress offline on a Local Area Network and I'm wondering how to stop WordPress from attempting to load "loader.js?ver=4.9.8" a javascript file from gstatic.com.
I've attempted adding define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL',true); in the wp-config.php file but that doesn't seem to stop the external traffic.
Currently anytime it attempts to load a webpage it takes 20 seconds plus attempting to load them from the internet until it gives us.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the hosts file to redirect gstatic.com to your local webserver.

```
127.0.0.1 gstatic.com
```

Also, there's a typo in `WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXETERNAL`, it must be `WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL`

Comment: Sorry the typo was just in my post not in the wp-config.php file.  I tried the hosts file redirect and it didn't seem to have any affect unfortunately.  Good idea though.